# Trying to pass arguments to a c++ function from python using boost.python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am attempting to run my c++ application from python. I have set up boost.python to allow me to do this; however, the c++ function I am trying to call requires console arguments which I used to enter into visual studio prior to building. Now I have this callable from python, I would love to pass these arguments through the python side.

I have tried to enter this just by entering the arguments into the python function but it has conversion issues.

Here is the error message:
`Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    cplusplus.function(int, str, str, str, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    function(int, char * __ptr64 * __ptr64)`

If there is a way I can convert the strings to char* __ptr64 that would be great. Or if there is an automatic way then even better.

using python 3.7 visual studio 16.3, and latest boost(1.71). Any other info I'll be more then happy to provide

Here is my c++ function declaration with arguments: `int notmain(int argc, char* argv[]) {`

And the python side calling it :
`print (cplusplus.function(Port, Server, user, pass, request))` 
(Port being an int and the rest being strings.)

Any advice/insight on this would be hugely appreciated, Thanks!

Breddie

Comment: Is your problem the conversion between `str` and `* __ptr64` or invalid number of arguments? Please add declarations of both functions.

Comment: I will edit the question now; pretty sure its a conversion issue, as i am just passing the exact same thing as what I was before when entering directly into c++ using console arguments?

Comment: I never worked with C++-Python interface, but it looks like sequence of 4 Python strings is not directly convertible to `char**`. You have to create an array of those strings somehow, and pass this array to C++.

Comment: No, doesnt seem to like it... I'll try find a solution and post it on this tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: You need to add wrapper function which takes something like `bp::list` or even a generic `bp::object` and converts that into what your `notmain` accepts. That will work (if it doesn't you're doing something wrong, but without seeing your code we can't really help you).